# Collect Cell Values from Column in Other Worksheet of the same WorkBook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and I'm currently working on some Excel Files.

The File I'm looking at now has a thousand of sheets. Except for the first sheet, they all look the same, something like :

http://i.imgur.com/t5UMte3.png

The first sheet has the name of each sheet in each row of col B:

http://i.imgur.com/AlH3pm5.png

What I am trying to do is, for each cells in col E that has been filled, to write the value into the first-sheet, in its corresponding row. It's like writing a report into the first-sheet for each sheets.
Hope I was clear enough ...

### Here is my code: Right now it could only change the very first value of column B.

```
Sub macro()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim d As Range
    Dim I As Integer

    For Each c In Feuil1322.UsedRange.Columns("B").Cells

        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

            If c.Value = ws.Name Then

                For Each d In ws.UsedRange.Columns("E").Cells
                    If Not IsEmpty(d.Value) Then
                    Feuil1322.Cells(c.End(xlUp).Row, 3).Formula = d.Value
                    End If
                Next

            End If

        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

---

Comment: To clarify: you want to put the first value found in column E from the 3APD032FA.ilv worksheet into C402 on the Issues worksheet. What if there are other values in 3APD032FA.ilv's column E? Should be next go to D402 and so on?

Comment: Not only the first value but everything I find in column E. I'd like them to be in the same cell, C402 for 3APD032FA.ilv, that's why I tried Formula instead of Value (heard it acted as a +=  operator)

Comment: I gather that each of the 3APXXXXXXX.ilv worksheets has a header row? There is a column header label in E1?

Comment: Yes they do, they all do, but that's not a big problem, I would change their value if I really need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column header label in each of the child worksheets is important as it will be used as the filter header to filter out blanks from column E and collect all visible values (e.g. *issue statements*).

```
Sub macro()
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, rng As Range, str As String

    on error goto Safe_Exit
    application.screenupdating = false
    application.enableevents = false

    Set wsI = Worksheets("Issues")

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            str = vbnullstring
            If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
            If CBool(Application.CountIf(wsI.Columns(2), .Name)) And _
              Application.CountA(.Columns(5)) > 2 Then
                With .Range(.Cells(2, 5), .Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp))
                    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
                    With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0)
                        For Each rng In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
                            str = str & rng.Value & Chr(10)
                        Next rng
                    End With
                    .AutoFilter Field:=1
                End With
                wsI.Cells(Application.Match(.Name, wsI.Columns(2), 0), 3) = Left(str, Len(str) - 1)
            End If
            If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
    Next ws

Safe_Exit:
    application.enableevents = true
    application.screenupdating = true
End Sub
```

I've collected together any statments found in column E and joined them with a `CHr(10)` (aka vbLF or line feed character).

This could be speeded up by turning off screen updating and enable events but it should run reasonably quick as is.

Comment: Note that I have modified the code to check for a counta of *more than 1* in column E of the child worksheets. I had originally written it for any value but if there is a column header label then there will always be at least 1 value.

Comment: Impressive thank you ! I'm trying it now and also trying to understand it haha. 
How do you turn off the screen update by the way ?

Comment: I've added appropriate error control and application environment code above.

Comment: Just tried it, it seems to work but it also takes the headers into the cell (not big issue), the bigger issue is that the value into the cells doesn't reset after each loop and I get the previous value as well as the new values.
Maybe if I put value = " " at the end of the loop it could solve this ?

Comment: My apologies; that was an oversight. To zero the string, use `str = vbnullstring` for each new worksheet (modified above). It shouldn't take the headers. Can you provide a better example of the child worksheets?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/SBmOO23.png
Here you go, should have sent this from the beginning. The code above is taking Comment/Defect. I could just it disappear actually with some simple code

Comment: Is E3 part of a merged cell that includes General Check or is  it an individual blank cell with a blue background?

Comment: Just background, General Check is on B3, E3 should be empty so I guess it can be ignored

Comment: OK, if you switch the counta to *greater than 2* and move the autofilter down a row so that it starts on row 2 then it shouldn't collect the header labels. Modified above.

Comment: I see, I also understand the code much better now. Thank you a lot !